# Template deduction for default template argument

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a class that looks similar to this:

```
template <class T = char>
struct C {
    T value;
};
```

Up to C++14, when I wanted to use it with the default template argument I always had to specify empty angle brackets:

```
void f() {
    C<> c;
    c.value = 'x';
}
```

Since C++17 supports class template argument deduction and explicit deduction guides, I wonder if there is a way now to make the above code work without specifying the empty angle brackets:

```
void f() {
    C c;
    c.value = 'x';
}
```

This code worked in GCC 8.0 if I compile it with `-std=gnu++17`. However, it still showed an error in Clang 6.0 and Visual Studio 15.7. Which compiler is correct in this situation?

I also tried specifying a deduction guide like this:

```
C() -> C<char>;
```

This also didn't help. Is that the correct syntax or is there even a way to specify deduction guides for a default constructor?

Comment: Notice that `C c; c.value = 42;` won't deduce type as `int`, deduction is done only at construction.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I know. It was only as example. My intention is to get rid of the empty angle brackets if the default template argument is used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This program is correct:

```
template <class T = char>
struct C {
    T value;
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.value = 'x';
}
```

clang just doesn't fully support class template argument deduction yet (note that it does compile on trunk).

---

Class template argument deduction will try to perform overload resolution on the candidate set:

```
template <class T=char> auto __f()     -> C<T>
template <class T=char> auto __f(C<T>) -> C<T>
```

with no initializer. That first one is a viable candidate (deducing `T` as `char`), the second one is not, so the first one is trivially the best viable candidate. So we end up with `c` having type `C<char>`. When we then do overload resolution on default construction, that works, so the program is fine.